# how to get Keycloak access token and store it in db for spring boot?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, access-token, keycloak

i want get the access token first and store the access token generated by keycloak  during login... in my db. i am using spring boot .

this is the code that i tried for getting the access token ..but result is nothing.... have a better solution?
..

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public String getCustomers()
 {
HttpServletRequest request =((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
                .getRequest();
        KeycloakAuthenticationToken token = (KeycloakAuthenticationToken) request.getUserPrincipal();
        KeycloakPrincipal principal = (KeycloakPrincipal) token.getPrincipal();
        KeycloakSecurityContext session = principal.getKeycloakSecurityContext();
        AccessToken accessToken = session.getToken();
        String a = principal.getName();
        String username = accessToken.getPreferredUsername();
        String realmName = accessToken.getIssuer();
        AccessToken.Access realmAccess = accessToken.getRealmAccess();
        String s = session.getToken().toString();
        System.out.println(s);
        return realmName;
..  }
```

i expect to get the access token generated by keycloak and store it in db.

```
@KeycloakConfiguration class SecurityConfig extends
  KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 /**
     * Registers the KeycloakAuthenticationProvider with the authentication manager.
     */


  @Autowired public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
  throws Exception { KeycloakAuthenticationProvider
  keycloakAuthenticationProvider=keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
  keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new
  SimpleAuthorityMapper());
  auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider); }

 /**
     * Defines the session authentication strategy.
     */
          @Bean

          @Override protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy
          sessionAuthenticationStrategy() { return new
          RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl()); }

          @Bean public KeycloakConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() { return new
          KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver(); }

          @Override protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
          super.configure(http); http .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/login*").hasRole("springrole") .anyRequest().permitAll(); } }
this is my keycloak configuration..
```

Comment: Please let us know why results you get and how they are different from what you expected.

Comment: i'm getting an  exception using this code for keycloak principal....  i actually want to get the key cloak access token first and then store it in my db... right now i'm not getting  none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U need login to keycloak, i see u just call custom "/login" and expect keycloak principal.

Comment: i have logged in..i have a working spring boot app and i have successfully logged into keycloak from my application but my requirement here is to get the access token when i login .... the above code is what i expect to get the keycloak access token(not  working).

Comment: attach configuration files

Comment: can you plz... tell me how? and what configuration should i use?

Comment: https://medium.com/@jinnerbichler/integrating-keycloak-4-with-spring-boot-2-microservices-6a6579f1d121

Comment: thank you  @Alex  but the configuration part is already done and i am able to use keycloak with my application ... now i actually want to get access toke and store it in my db for a particular user...thats my problem..can you help

Comment: can u attach you configuration files and login to keycloak

Comment: i have a client called 'springboot' with a user name 'springuser' having a role 'springrole'.. with user having some credentials ... now i want to get and store the accesstoken for this user when i login... the above code is what i have used to get the token..but it isnt working  .

Comment: i have added my config

Comment: and u should create keycloak admin part and login to keycloak manually in u endpoint, after that u get a token from keycloak admin client and when u send http call with this token, u get keycloak principal

Comment: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.8/server_development/index.html#example-using-java

Comment: thank you so much @alex  i am able to get the access token now ...half of my problem is solved ....next is to store the token in my local db ...could you help in that ?

Comment: if u use jwt token u don't need save it in db

Comment: i do need it to be stored in db .....as i will be using it later to check the user... do you have any idea?

Comment: @TJ32 jwt token has a user info. If u pass token with correct http header (Authorization Bearer) Spring Security encode user info. it is benefit of jwt token.

Comment: could you give me a reference document or an example  @alex