# Get Keycloak AccessToken in controller

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, access-token

I am trying to get the access token after a successfully login, and after a lot of researched I got to this post, [how to get Keycloak access token and store it in db for spring boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58285994/how-to-get-keycloak-access-token-and-store-it-in-db-for-spring-boot), where it's said to make a Keycloak login manually, but I don't know how. The link to the document in the comments doesn't work anymore.

I also tired to get it thought the headers, but no Authorization header is sent.

```
String authHeader = servletRequest.getHeader("Authorization"); //returns null
if (authHeader != null
        && !authHeader.isEmpty()
        && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer")) {

    String accessToken = authHeader.substring("Bearer".length()).trim();

    if (accessToken != null) {
        return new ResponseEntity(true, HttpStatus.OK);

    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity(false, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
} else {
    log.error("Invalid authorization header. ");
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

I tried also to get it throught the Principal, but I get an error:

java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationToken cannot be cast to class org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken

```
ServletRequestAttributes servletRequestAttributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
        .currentRequestAttributes();
HttpServletRequest request = servletRequestAttributes.getRequest();
KeycloakAuthenticationToken userPrincipal = (KeycloakAuthenticationToken) request.getUserPrincipal();
SimpleKeycloakAccount userPrincipalDetails = (SimpleKeycloakAccount) userPrincipal.getDetails();
return userPrincipalDetails
        .getKeycloakSecurityContext()
        .getToken();
```

The same error is displayed if I try:

```
KeycloakAuthenticationToken authenticatication = (KeycloakAuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

I can login/logout, but I cannot get the accessToken...

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final KeycloakLogoutHandler keycloakLogoutHandler;

    public SecurityConfig(KeycloakLogoutHandler keycloakLogoutHandler) {
        this.keycloakLogoutHandler = keycloakLogoutHandler;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider  = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/somepage/*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.oauth2Login()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First, do not use Keycloak libs for Spring: [it is (very) deprecated](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187). Instead use:

- `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` if your app is a REST API. Instruction in the first of [this series of tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials).
- `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` if your app serves UI (with thymeleaf or whatever)

The exact type of `Authentication` returned by `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` depends on your app being a client or a resource-server and it being configured with JWT decoder or token introspection, but all expose the Bearer access-token string. Just get it from there.

In the case your app is a resource-server (REST API), you might use one of the spring-boot starters I maintain for `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` auto-configuration from properties. This quite simplifies the configuration compared to the first tutorial linked before:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <!-- replace "webmvc" with "weblux" if your app is reactive -->
    <!-- replace "jwt" with "introspecting" to use token introspection instead of JWT decoding -->
    <artifactId>spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server</artifactId>
    <!-- this version is to be used with spring-boot 3.0.0-RC1, use 5.x for spring-boot 2.6.x or before -->
    <version>6.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
@EnableMethodSecurity
public static class WebSecurityConfig { }
```

```
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].location=https://localhost:8443/realms/master
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].authorities.claims=realm_access.roles,ressource_access.some-client.roles

com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.cors[0].path=/some-api
```

The Authentication for authorized requests will the be `JwtAuthenticationToken`:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/demo")
public class DemoController {

    @GetMapping("/access-token")
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public String getAccessToken(JwtAuthenticationToken auth) {
        return auth.getToken().getTokenValue();
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: be carefull with what you do with access-tokens and who you expose it to. If it leaks, it might be used for identity usurpation.

Comment: Do you mean that I should not extend the KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just follow the two links in the answer for announcement and recommanded alternative.  What I expose in the answer is simplest complete security config for a servlets resource-server. In tutorials linked, you'll find the way do the same with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` only, but it's way more verbose.